# I have a issue in executing the below database query

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

I have an issue in executing the below database query.

I am using Oracle 11g Enterprise Edition

Query 1:

```
SELECT d.department_id, max(salary), min(salary), avg(salary), count(*) no_of_employees
FROM departments d, employees e
WHERE e.department_id = d.department_id
GROUP BY d.department_id
```

Result: successful output

Query 2:

```
SELECT d.department_id, d.department_name, max(salary), min(salary), avg(salary), count(*) no_of_employees
FROM departments d, employees e
WHERE e.department_id = d.department_id
GROUP BY d.department_id
```

Result:

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Can anybody help me out with this issue?
Please let me know what is wrong with this expression.

Answer (score 3):

you must also group by department_name

Comment: thanks for the help..
the below query worked for me

select d.department_id, d.department_name, max(salary), min(salary), avg(salary) , count(*) no_of_employees
from departments d, employees e
where e.department_id = d.department_id
group by d.department_id, department_name

Answer (score 1):

You need to GROUP BY all the columns that you don't have an aggregation function (MAX, COUNT, etc).  Therefore:

```
select d.department_id
     , d.department_name
     , max(salary), min(salary), avg(salary) , count(*) no_of_employees
from departments d, employees e
where e.department_id = d.department_id
group by d.department_id, d.department_name;
```

But you should also consider doing an ANSI join instead:

```
select department_id
     , department_name
     , max(salary), min(salary), avg(salary) , count(*) no_of_employees
from departments
join employees USING (department_id)
group by department_id, department_name;
```